# Pyplot and Seaborn - How to add markers to the legend when they were produced by a seaborn plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am plotting 5 sets of data onto a single graph. For each set of data, I need to plot the scatter graph of the points (which I do using `seaborn.regplot`) and a line function which was separately fitted to the points.

The problem is that I can add the lines to the legend, but I can't add the markers from the regplot since I don't have any object handle on it. Here is my code:

```
    f, ax = plt.subplots()

    #Plotting the scatter points onto the axes object ax
    sns.regplot(x='logF', y='R', data=MeanParams[(0 < MeanParams.M) & (0.2 > MeanParams.M)], 
            fit_reg=False, color='g', marker='+', ax=ax)
    sns.regplot(x='logF', y='R', data=MeanParams[(0.2 < MeanParams.M) & (0.5 > MeanParams.M)], 
            fit_reg=False, color='y', marker='x', ax=ax)
    sns.regplot(x='logF', y='R', data=MeanParams[(0.5 < MeanParams.M) & (1.5 > MeanParams.M)], 
            fit_reg=False, color='r', marker='x', ax=ax)
    sns.regplot(x='logF', y='R', data=MeanParams[(1.5 < MeanParams.M) & (3.5 > MeanParams.M)], 
            fit_reg=False, color='b', marker='x', ax=ax)
    sns.regplot(x='logF', y='R', data=MeanParams[(3.5 < MeanParams.M)], 
            fit_reg=False, color='k', marker='+', ax=ax)

    #plotting the lines onto the same axes object
    line1, = ax.plot(x, y_0, 'k-', linewidth=2)
    line2, = ax.plot(x, y_1, 'k--', linewidth=2)
    line3, = ax.plot(x, y_2, 'k-.', linewidth=3)
    line4, = ax.plot(x, y_3, 'k:', linewidth=3)
    line5, = ax.plot(x, y_4, 'r--', linewidth=2)

    #creating the legend
    ax.legend((line1,line2,line3,line4,line5), 
         (r'0.0 - 0.2', r'0.2 - 0.5', r'0.5 - 1.5', r'1.5 - 3.5', r'3.5 + '), 
         title='Mass Range', loc='upper left')
```

As you can see, I have handles on the line objects produced by `ax.plot()` but since I did the scatter plot with `seaborn.regplot()` I don't have any handle on the markers.

One easy way to solve this would be to persumably just use the pyplot scatter instead. But I guess I'm just asking out of curiosity, is there a way to pull out the line/marker objects so that I can put them into a legend as well?

Comment: If you pass names to `label=` and then call `ax.legend` they will appear.